# Unity Spawning Objects Out of Order Client-Side

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

At the moment my project group and I are trying to synchronize the game objects between clients and server. Everything is going well except we noticed one thing: when the client signs in the spawn order of objects are all mismatched and they spawn out of order. This is problematic when you have, let's say two different objects with two different prefabs and they swap positions. I don't know why this happens, but this is what it looks like.

[image]

In the picture, the brick next to the player should be the bomb in the middle. On the server side, the bomb is in the correct position. On the client, the objects are swapped. Is there something we're doing wrong in Unity? I can provide code if needed, but I was more focused on describing this phenomenon.

**Update**: So I found that the Net IDs are swapped on Client-side vs Server-side.

Comment: Interesting. Could you provide the code where you assign the image(sprite I assume) to the object and where you instantiate the object?

Comment: We just have empty game object variables in the script and drag the prefabs in on the inspector so there isn't any code.

Asides from registering prefabs on ClientScene and on Server

@Hristo

Comment: Are you using UNet?

Comment: We're using the lower level API of UNET, yes. We're not allowed to use NetworkManager. Currently using NetworkServer, NetworkClient, and NetworkIdentity. We don't use NetworkTransform.

@Fiffe

Comment: Maybe try adding a syncvar to your object that will tell clients what kind of object it is and based on that clients will select appropriate prefab, would that work?

Comment: If fixing the Net IDs problem fixed it, then please write that up as an answer and accept it so its easy to tell that your problem is resolved.

Comment: @ashbygeek I couldn't solve it yet but I did notice the issue